# Safely Inserting Strings Into a SQLite3 UNION Query Using Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm aware that the best way to prevent sql injection is to write Python queries of this form (or similar):

```
query = 'SELECT %s %s from TABLE'
fields = ['ID', 'NAME']
cur.execute(query, fields)
```

The above will work for a single query, but what if we want to do a UNION of 2 SQL commands? I've set this up via sqlite3 for sake of repeatability, though technically I'm using pymysql. Looks as follows:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('dummy.db')
cur = conn.cursor()
query = 'CREATE TABLE DUMMY(ID int AUTO INCREMENT, VALUE varchar(255))'
query2 = 'CREATE TABLE DUMMy2(ID int AUTO INCREMENT, VALUE varchar(255)'
try:
    cur.execute(query)
    cur.execute(query2)
except:
    print('Already made table!')

tnames = ['DUMMY1', 'DUMMY2']
sqlcmds = []
for i in range(0,2):
    query = 'SELECT %s FROM {}'.format(tnames[i])
    sqlcmds.append(query)

fields = ['VALUE', 'VALUE']
sqlcmd = ' UNION '.join(sqlcmds)
cur.execute(sqlcmd, valid_fields)
```

When I run this, I get a sqlite Operational Error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error
```

I've validated the query prints as expected with this output:

```
INSERT INTO DUMMY VALUES(%s) UNION INSERT INTO DUMMY VALUES(%s)
```

All looks good there. What is the issue with the string substitutions here? I can confirm that running a query with direct string substitution works fine. I've tried it with both selects and inserts.

EDIT: I'm aware there are multiple ways to do this with executemany and a few other. I need to do this with UNION for the purposes I'm using this for because this is a very, very simplified example fo the operational code I'm using

Comment: you can't union a insert and you can use placeholders for column in select too and you show us sqllite3 code with an error message from sqllite3?

Comment: @Zach - what do you try to do? batch insert?

Comment: @nbk It is technically a MySQL query I changed to make more reproduceable, but fair enough. I've made the mods to the title and code to use select queries and call it what it is- a sqlite example

Comment: You need to use string formatting for _identifiers_ - the names of tables, columns etc.  You use _parameter substitution_ for _values_.  The placeholder used for _values_ in Python's sqlite3 module is a `?`, not `%s`.

Answer (score 0):

The code below executes few INSERTS at once

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('dummy.db')
cur = conn.cursor()
query = 'CREATE TABLE DUMMY(ID int AUTO INCREMENT NOT NULL, VALUE varchar(255))'
try:
    cur.execute(query)
except:
    print('Already made table!')

valid_fields = [('ya dummy',), ('stupid test example',)]

cur.executemany('INSERT INTO DUMMY (VALUE) VALUES (?)',valid_fields)
```

Comment: Yeah, this will work for multiple queries. I guess I should specify in the question I really need this with the UNION pattern though